# android java Finding X and Y location

Tags: java, android

How Can I find the X and Y of a certain area on my emulator? Cause I want to make it if you click at a certain spot something will happen. But instead of making a invisible ImageView there I can just click on the X and Y.

How can I do about finding a X and Y location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following to get the X-Y coordinates of your touch event.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // MotionEvent object holds X-Y values
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            String text = "You clicked at x = " + event.getX() + " and y = " + event.getY();
            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Draw a `canvas` somewhere on your screen, wherever you want to click, and then set its `onClick` attribute.